# How to show most recent inventory per storage place?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I’m making a search function for my products. When a user search for a product, they must find it in one or more storage places on the last inventory registration date.

For each storage place will be one or more inventories with different products stored in it.

For so far I've this and my code is working fine. It shows the most recent inventory  at the top. But if I’ve created more than one inventory for the same storage place, I only want the most recent date of each storage place to be shown.

Here's a screenshot how it looks like for now:

[image]

I only want *24/12/2015 storage 1* and *22/12/2015 storage Test* to be shown. Because I don’t need to show older inventories of storage 1.

Below Is my code.

controllers.js:

```
.controller('InventoryCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $filter, Category, Inventory) {

$scope.categories = Category;

$scope.searchInventory = function(category){
var word = category.Category;

var ref = new Firebase('https://vivid-heat-2430.firebaseio.com/');

var invenRef = ref.child('Inventories');

var arrInv = [];

invenRef.orderByChild("Date").on("child_added", function(snapshot){
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var store = data.Inventory;
  var prod = data.Products;

  var test = Object.keys(prod);

  for( var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
    if (test[i] == word) {
      console.log("Storage place: " + data.Inventory + " Datum inventaris: " + data.Date);

     var convertDate = $filter('date')(data.Date, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
     arrInv.push(convertDate + " " + data.Inventory);
     console.log(arrInv);
    };        
  }; 
  $scope.show = arrInv;
  $scope.$digest(); 
});

 };
})
```

index.html:

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-repeat="category in categories" class="item-accordion" ng-model="checked.check" value="{{category.Category}}" ng-click="searchInventory(category)">
          <p>{{category.Category}}</p>
        </ion-radio>
        <br>
      </ion-list>


      <div>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-model="item" ng-repeat="item in show.slice().reverse() track by $index">
              <span ng-bind="item"> {{item}}
              </span>
            </ion-item>


        </ion-list>
      </div>
```

Can someone please help me and tell me how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Comment: Have you tried - 
invenRef.orderByChild("Date").limitToLast(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
//Do your stuff
});

Comment: Yes, but when I have the same product stored in a third storage place it will only show 2 storage places instead of 3.

Comment: Holy crap, your code is all like: http://imgur.com/GPCitof

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL database, this could be accomplished by a `group by` clause. But that doesn't exist in Firebase. In a NoSQL database you have to model the data to fit with the way you want to use it. I recommend reading more about NoSQL data modeling, for example in [this article](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

In this case you have a requirement to show the most recently updated inventories. So you should model the inventories by their (most recent) update timestamp:

```
lastUpdatePerInventory
    Storage_1: 1451080004970
    Storage_Test: 1450993624134
```

This data structure is *in addition* to all the data you already store for your other use-cases. It's up to your application to keep all the data structures in sync. So if you add a product to an inventory, you should also update the `` for that inventory.

```
function addProductToInventory(product, inventoryName) {
    ref.child('products')
        .push(...); // whatever you do to store a product in an inventory
    ref.child("lastUpdatePerInventory")
       .child(inventoryName)
       .set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
}
```

*Advanced usage*: if you're worried that the function should be transaction, you can write it to make use of Firebase's multi-location `update()` function:

```
function addProductToInventory(product, inventoryName) {
    var updates = {};
    var newId = ref.push().key(); // determine a new unique key
    updates['products/'+key] = ...// whatever store for a product in an inventory
    updates["lastUpdatePerInventory/inventoryName"] = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    ref.update(updates);
}
```